# Generic property in class

Tags: c#, generics, keyvaluepair

I have a class which has 2 properties key and value, key will always be used as a string type, however value of `value` property need to be generic.

So i want to create a generic type just for the property instead of class, because if i make a generic for class, the type which i use for the class will be used for all the items in the generic list class for all the property.

Can anyone tell me how could i achieve this. Below is the class:

```
   public class KeyValuePairs
    {
        public string Key { get; set; }
        public object Value { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what is wrong with using `KeyValuePair<string, WhaterverTypeYouWant>` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do *exactly* that, this wouldn't work.

Imagine you *could* write the following:

```
public class KeyValuePairs
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public T Value<T> { get; set; }
}
```

What would be the type of the `foo` variable in the following code?

```
var pair = new KeyValuePairs();
var foo = pair.Value;
```

Ok, now let's *suppose* the language allows you do to that:

```
var pair = new KeyValuePairs();
var foo = pair.Value<int>;
```

Well... how would the following code behave?

```
var pair = new KeyValuePairs();
pair.Value = new Thread();
var foo = pair.Value<int>;
```

As you can see, there's good reason why the language disallows that.

---

You can do it the following way, of course:

```
public class KeyValuePairs<TValue>
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public TValue Value { get; set; }
}
```

(or just use `System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, TValue>`)

Or you could replace the property with a method pair:

```
// Warning: bad code!
public class KeyValuePairs<TValue>
{
    private object _value;

    public string Key { get; set; }

    public TValue GetValue<TValue>()
    {
        return _value;
    }

    public void SetValue<TValue>(TValue value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }
}
```

but you *clearly* have a design problem if you're considering do do that, as this has *no advantage whatsoever* over an `object`-typed property.

---

Here's a solution using `KeyValuePair<string, object>`:

```
var list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>();
list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("string", "Hello, World!"));
list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("int", 42));
list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("bool", true));

foreach (var item in list)
    Console.WriteLine("[{0}] = {1}", item.Key, item.Value);
```

And here's a [demo](http://ideone.com/l5VKbM).

Comment: The problem with making the class generic is i am using the class as a list like List<KeyValuePair<int, int> objList = new List<KeyValuePair>(); this would simply mean all the key and value will be int, or whatever you provide at the time of initialization, but in my case, the value of the value could be of any type, also i can't make it object Type, as i couldn't get the actual type the property has been assigned to.

Comment: Then you can simply use `KeyValuePair<string, object>`... what's the problem with this approach?

Comment: Say i have 2 items in the KeyValuePair<string, object>
1. string, int e.g: "abbas", 123
2. string, boolean e.g: "abbas", true
with the above initialization i will always get the type of the value argument as object and never int and boolean, that's the actual problem is, hope i am clear now, with my requirement

Comment: That would still work as the value types would get boxed. You can then cast back the values to the type you want (or use `is`/`as` to test for a given type, or `Value.GetType()` to get the runtime type).

Comment: if you don't mind can you give me an example where there are 2 items in KeyValuePairs<T> where one should be string, int and another should be string, boolean, below one i tried, but didn't worked:

List<KeyValuePairs<int>> inserts = new List<KeyValuePairs<int>>();
inserts.Add(new KeyValuePairs<string>("abbas", "123"));

It expects the Generic type once defined for the KeyValuePairs should be used for all items in the list.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78038/discussion-between-abbas-and-lucas-trzesniewski).

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is:

```
public class KeyValuePairs<TValue>
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public TValue Value { get; set; }
}
```

The long one is: why do you not use the `System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>` struct with `string` for `TKey` and anything useful for `TValue`?

Example with your generic class:

```
var key = new KeyValuePairs<int>{ Key = "abc", Value = 123 };
```

---

I would make the key immutable, because it is not a good idea to change it once the object has been added to a collection relying on the key:

```
public class KeyValuePairs<TValue>
{
    public KeyValuePairs(string key, TValue value)
    {
        _key = key;
        Value = value;
    }

    private readonly string _key;
    public string Key { get { return _key; } }

    public TValue Value { get; set; }
}
```

Example:

```
var key = new KeyValuePairs<int>("abc", 123);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know how to do this, I suggest you read further into generics before you continue (start [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)). To enlighten you, it would be achived with the following code.

```
public class KeyValuePairs<T>
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

However, a class such as this already exists in the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace. [KeyValuePair](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).